Why ptp_stop/ptp_start function is not called in igb_suspend/igb_resume?
I am new to IGB drivers.
Note:https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb/igb_main.c
My question may be silly for this post here.

Why does the ptp_stop function not get called in igb_suspend?
Why does the ptp_start function not get called in igb_resume?

Is it intentionally doing? (or) is that any background history reason for this?
Could you please share your thoughts?

The question is not about git or GitHub, even less about github-actions. Please do not spam unrelated tags.

Please read this Q&A then [edit] your question accordingly.
